Can I pass a variable type as a parameter in a function in Python?
Can I pass a variable type as a parameter in a function in Python? I'm trying to do something that needs me to input a data type. The current code I have is along the lines of:
def Function_Name(Data_Type, *args):
     for i in args:
          if type(i) == Data_Type:
               return(XXXX)

I know can do an input of a string and then convert it into a data type once in the function, but is there a way to just input the data type directly? I also know that you can store a data type (ex: int) in a var and use it that way, but it won't let me input it into a function as a parameter.

How are you trying to call this function? And what is the expected result?

Answer is "yes". And now?

function_Name(str) performs the equivalent of Data_Type = str.

When you say "input the data type directly", do you mean have the user enter it on the terminal and using input() to read it? There's no syntax for type literals, type names are simply variables.

yes. you can just test this out yourself, def foo(data_type): print(isinstance(42, data_type)), then try it wiht foo(str); foo(float); foo(int)

Yes, you can do this. Classes are first class objects in Python, so you could call:
Function_Name(int, a, b, c)

and it would return for the first element of a, b or c that was of type int  (exactly, not a subclass). If none of them are of the desired type, then the loop with end without a return, and the function will implicitly return None.
Note that when comparing types, you're more likely to want to test either:

if isinstance(i, Data_Type): (to allow subclasses and virtual subclasses to pass), or
if type(i) is Data_Type: (types are singletons, and it's slightly more efficient to use identity testing, rather than potentially performing rich comparison checks that should never pass)

The former would allow bool to pass if the argument was int (because bool is a subclass of int), while the latter would not (but would do so more efficiently than what you wrote), so choose based on what you intend.

You can, but you should use isinstance to check the type.
def function_name(data_type, *args):
    for i in args:
        if isinstance(i, date_type):
            return 42


assert function_name(int, 'c', 3.14159, 6) == 42
assert function_name(str) is None


To add to the answer provided by @ShadowRanger. The generic type object is literally just object, if you need a far larger context to work with. Though, depending on how you handle it, your performance will suffer.
The best way to describe this for future discussion is the term anonymous.
def test_method(variable: object):
    if (isinstance(variable, str)):
            print(variable)
    else:
            print(type(variable))

var = "This is a string"

test_method(var)
>>> This is a string

var = 42

test_method(var)
>>> <class 'int'>


I really don't understand what you are trying to say here. you are using object simply as an annotation. What does that have to do with the question? I understand that you are trying to add on to another answer
